# (iphone) is there a function call(UIImage related) I shouldn't do in non-main thread here?

Tags: iphone, background, uiimage

I'm trying to create UIImage from background thread.
**I wonder if any call I use here shouldn't be done in background.**
Thank you

```
// defined below 
CGContextRef context = CreateARGBBitmapContext(entireRect.size);                                                                                                                                                                                                        

CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, originalImage.CGImage);                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: imageRef];                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
CGImageRelease(imageRef);                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

CGContextRelease(context);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

return img;
```

Where CreateARGBBitmapContext is defined as below.

```
CGContextRef CreateARGBBitmapContext(CGSize size)
{
    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *          bitmapData;
    int             bitmapByteCount;
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    // Get image width, height. We'll use the entire image.                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    size_t pixelsWide = size.width;
    size_t pixelsHigh = size.height;

    // Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    // example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and                                                                                                                                                                                                
    // alpha.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);
//  bitmapBytesPerRow = (int) round( pow( 2.0, trunc( log((double) bitmapBytesPerRow) / log(2.0) ) + 1.0 ) );                                                                                                                                                                 
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

    // Use the generic RGB color space.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    if (colorSpace == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating color space\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    // where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    NSMutableData* mutableData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: bitmapByteCount];
    bitmapData = [mutableData mutableBytes];
    if (bitmapData == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
        CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
        return NULL;
    }

    // Create the bitmap context. We want pre-multiplied ARGB, 8-bits                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    // per component. Regardless of what the source image format is                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    // (CMYK, Grayscale, and so on) it will be converted over to the format                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    // specified here by CGBitmapContextCreate.                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                     pixelsWide,
                                     pixelsHigh,
                                     8,      // bits per component    
                                    bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    if (context == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
    }

    // Make sure and release colorspace before returning                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

    return context;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line should be in the main thread:

```
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: imageRef];
```

The rest of the code looks like it would be ok to be in a different thread.

Any interaction with UIKit must be in the main thread.  That's why creating a UIImage (or even something like setting the image of a UIImageView) must be done in the main thread.  Fortunately, the heavy work, like downloading an image or probably even drawing one as you're doing, can be done in a separate thread.  Then, you return to the main thread just to create the UIImage.

Using Grand Central Dispatch and some blocks, the following code might work for you:

`dispatch_queue_t drawingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Drawing image", NULL);
    dispatch_async(drawingQueue, ^{
        CGContextRef context = CreateARGBBitmapContext(entireRect.size);                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, originalImage.CGImage);                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);           
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: imageRef];                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            CGImageRelease(imageRef); 
        });
    });
    dispatch_release(drawingQueue);`

If you're not familiar with Grand Central Dispatch, try googling it.  I'm afraid I don't know of a good tutorial for it.  Hope this is helpful.

CORRECTION:

My response above is wrong.  The UIImage CAN be created in the main thread.

While most interaction with UIKit must be done in the main thread, there are a few exceptions, including UIImage, UIColor, UIFont and Core Graphics.  These are all threadsafe.

(Note that I believe UIImageView is not threadsafe.  So that if you were to set the image of a UIImageView, then you would have to return to the main thread.  A variation of the above code would still be useful for interaction with other UIKit objects, and should not do any damage in this case-- other than unnecessarily complicating things.)

Comment: ah!!, is there no way of creating UIImage from background thread?.. If so, I should return CGImageRef and let the caller performSelectorOnMainThread to create UIImage from the imageRef, and CGImageRelease(imageRef); ?

Comment: ah actually I can do performSelector in the UIImage create function with waitUntilDone: YES, nvm performSelector won't return a value;

Comment: I'm not familiar with performSelectorOnMainThread, but check out the above edit.  That should work for you.  Anyway, the idea is to do the heavy work in a secondary thread, and return to the main thread only to do the final adjustment in UIKit.  (Creating a UIImage with a CGImage, as you're doing, is pretty light work.)

Comment: Please note my correction.  It could have all been done in the background thread.  Sorry for giving you wrong advice on this.  (I was under the impression that any interaction with UIKit had to be done in the main thread, and just found out that there are exceptions.)  My advice must have caused you a bit of extra trouble, but I hope it didn't affect how your program ran.